# Finding Parallelogram Vertices?

Tags: geometry

How I can calculate coordinates of vertices of a Parallelogram when I have four points located on its edges and four unit vector indicating the direction of each edge?

I want to find coordinates of v1,v2,v3,v4 in this picture:  [image]

Comment: You can construct an equation for a line for each point. (Start with point-slope form for example).  Then start calculating where each pair of lines intersect by solving the system of two equations with two unknowns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have four lines $r_i = p_i + t \cdot uv_i$ for $i=1,2,3,4$. Now You just have to find the intersection points of each nonparallel pair of lines. That means you get each time a system of linear equations e.g.:

$$p_1 + t\cdot uv_1 = p_2 + s\cdot uv_2$$ which you have to solve for $t$ and $s$.

(In 3D: As you get more equations than variables you do have an intersection point if you find a pair $(s,t)$ that satisfies the three equations. If not there is no intersectionpoint. )

If youve found a pair, you just have to plug them into one of the equations and you get the vertex, in my example:

$$v_2 = p_1 + t\cdot uv_1 = p_2 + s\cdot uv_2$$

Comment: Good explanation - thanks :)